# Ошибка «Bad Gateway for url»?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, веб-сервер

Всем привет!
Запустил своего бота на бесплатном сервере python, бот работает стабильно первые 30-40 минут, а потом выдает ошибку: **502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: `https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getDialogs`** 
в чем может быть дело?
полный скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

спасибо

Comment: ВК глючит, бывает. Ловите ошибку и повторяйте отправку запроса через несколько секунд

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: try-except, как обычно в питоне делают

Comment: но у меня весь код в `try` поставлен..

Comment: аа, у меня одна перменная которая отвечает за получение сообщений вне `try`, пофиксю пойду